# Package Conda Environment with Azure Synapse Spark Jobs

Tags: azure, pyspark, conda, azure-synapse

I am trying to use azure synapse for running spark jobs. Based on the documentation, synapse allows to install third party libraries via [workspace packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-azure-portal-add-libraries#workspace-packages)

However, in the azure synapse command reference I can see that it supports [archives option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/synapse/spark/job?view=azure-cli-latest#az-synapse-spark-job-submit)
Does it mean that I can reference a packaged conda environment from blob storage and ensure that all the necessary packages are available in all the nodes?

To simulate I created a small conda environment with single external package `humanize`

```
  conda create -y -n hornet_conda_env
  conda activate hornet_conda_env
  conda install -c conda-forge humanize
  conda pack -f -o hornet_conda_env.tar.gz
```

The entry spark job file as `script.py`

```
  import humanize
  import datetime as dt

  print(humanize.naturalday(dt.datetime.now()))
```

The script and conda environment package (`hornet_conda_env.tar.gz`) are uploaded to Azure Blob Storage and a spark job is created with the reference to the script.

The spark job definition is invoked via command line using `az cli` as follows:

```
az synapse spark job submit \
--workspace-name <workspace_name> \ 
--spark-pool-name <pool_name> 
--executor-size Small 
--executors 2 
--language PySpark 
--main-definition-file abfss://<full_path_for_entry_spark_job>.script.py \
--name <name> \
--archives abfss://<full_path_for_conda_package>/hornet_conda_env.tar.gz
```

The script execution fails with the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'humanize'` meaning that conda environment is not installed as referenced in archives.

Does synapse allow this kind of conda environment packaging and distribution?

### Update 1

I am trying to use this package locally and I am unable to use the same as well. I am trying to use this outside the conda environment and I am getting the same issue as `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'humanize'`

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 \
spark-submit \
--master "local[3]" \
--conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 \
--archives ~/workspace/cuezen/hornet/hornet_env.tar.gz#environment  \
~/workspace/cuezen/hornet/hornet.py
```

Comment: Corrected the typo. I have installed the `humanize` like `conda install -c conda-forge humanize` and then packaged the environment. Still unable to reference the zip package on the synapse.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to get rid of modules not found error:

1. Enable virtual environment in your terminal. Below are few commands:

   ```
    python -m venv .venv
    .venv\Scripts\activate
    #add the module in req.txt to install it.
    pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```
2. Make sure this more is present in site packages.
3. If it is not present add it explicitly by comparing it with azure-python-sdk or humanize module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the `--configuration` parameter with the override to the `spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON` config. Something like

```
az synapse spark job submit \
--workspace-name <workspace_name> \ 
--spark-pool-name <pool_name> 
--executor-size Small 
--executors 2 
--language PySpark 
--main-definition-file abfss://<full_path_for_entry_spark_job>.script.py \
--name <name> \
--archives abfss://<full_path_for_conda_package>/hornet_conda_env.tar.gz
--configuration "@config.json"
```

And have a config.json file locally with these contents

```
{"spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON":"./<env_name>/bin/python"}
```

Unfortunately this causes the synapse pool to use this environment instead of the one that it has by default, which may mean that you need to add all the dependencies there (however the file could be huge).

If you find a way to load dependencies for both environments let me know.

Edit:
Did some research and you will need the base [yml](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/Synapse/tree/main/Spark/Python) files for the environment to work, which are around 4.5GB.